# How to give local system path in ssh?

Tags: java, ssh, path

I'm trying to insert records from local directory path in SSH but it shows "file not found" because it does not recognize the path. But if I give sft directory then it recognise the path.

This is the code:

**Local directory path:**

```
./putmsgE1E2.ksh LPDWA123 ABC.GD.SENDCORRESPONDENCE.BATCH.INPUT XPRESSION.TEST /Users/admin/Desktop/important.txt;
```

and I tried using `c:/Users/admin/Desktop/important.txt`

**SFT Directory:**

```
./putmsgE1E2.ksh LPDWA123 ABC.GD.SENDCORRESPONDENCE.BATCH.INPUT XPRESSION.TEST /abchome/abc123/1.txt;
```

I have inputs in the txt file in my local directory; I want to poll that files to the server. Hope someone finds a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command on Linux systems:

```
scp /path/to/your/local/file remoteUser@some_address:/home/remoteUser/Documents
```

Comment: i need to give path in windows system

Comment: did you know how to upload files to remote user from local directory.